# All Core Data properties turn nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm a little new to core data, but as such I don't think I'm doing anything to complicated here.  I have an object persisted to core data, it has a pretty simple one to one relationship with another object.  I am showing all instances of my object with a simple fetch request and a table view.  Everything works great.

If you stick around on the table view and scroll around long enough, suddenly all the table cells go blank.  I've tracked the problem down to my array of core data objects; the array still exists, the persisted objects still exist, but all my properties are suddenly set to nil.

What would cause this kind of behavior?  I have subscribed to the Core Data Will and Did save methods and they are not getting fired.  Are there any other tips I can use to debug this problem?

EDIT - included the method used to persist the object below:

```
- (void) persistLongActivity: (NSDictionary*) longActivityData 
{
PersistedLongActivity *toPersist = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"PersistedLongActivity" inManagedObjectContext: [self managedObjectContext]];

toPersist.startDate = [longActivityData valueForKey:@"startDate"];
toPersist.endDate = [longActivityData valueForKey:@"endDate"];
toPersist.type = [longActivityData valueForKey:@"type"];

[self saveContext];
}
```

Comment: You will need to post some code, maybe an example of how you create an new entity and save it.

Comment: In your save method, do you check if there was a save error?

Comment: Can you post the `saveContext` method?

Comment: how do you create your context? are you keeping it retained? are you resetting your context?

Comment: Thanks @DanShelly I have a lot of boiler plate Core Data code copied from other places that manages the context.  It appears the context is thread dependent, which I believe was causing my problem (see below answer).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I believe the problem was that I was retrieving from Core Data on a background thread.  I was attempting to take the data retrieval off the main thread so I didn't kill user performance, but it sounds like Core Data off the main thread is a bad idea?  Either way, keeping the retrieval on the main thread seems to solve the problem at hand.

If someone can explain why retrieving from Core Data in a background thread results in this behavior, or if someone can provide a better solution to retrieve from Core Data without delaying the main thread, I'd love to hear it in the comments.

Comment: Obviously a context is thread dependent. you cannot use managed object across threads and contexts only object IDs are safe to be transferred among threads/contexts. you BG contexts was deallocated resulting in all registered objects nullified properties.

Comment: Basically, Core Data is not thread safe, and crossing threads and/or queues is going to screw things up. Using Core Data in the background is fine so long as you do it right.

Comment: Thanks, @TomHarrington, but what is the "right" way?  My UI code has to run on the main thread, but it sounds like if I ever retrieve data objects on a background thread they can't be used on the main thread?  How do I bridge the two?

Comment: Look into queue confinement and the `performBlock` and `performBlockAndWait` methods.

Answer (score 0):

They are disappearing because A.R.C. is killing them off from memory. Your pointers are dyeing. Create stronger references.

Comment: All my properties are set to retain.  That's what Core Data auto generates anyway.